# In Sublime Text 2 is there a tool to "colorize" git add/deletes in a COMMIT_EDITMSG file?

Tags: git, sublimetext2, colorize

When I git commit, I do a `$ gcv` which is an alias in my .bash_profile for `git commit -v`. The information in that file is great. I like to review what I did so I can make a concise message.

Recently, I figured out how to "colorize" my git output in iTerm2 and it's beautiful. My brain has gotten used to quickly identifying the red and green so I can see the adds and deletes very easily.

Question is: I can see my `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file in Sublime, but can I get it to open with the same colorized lines I'm seeing in iTerm2?

Answer (score 9):

There is a way! I finally figured it out!

First make sure that you have the subl command for the terminal, and set subl as your git editor (with the -w option):
Edit your .bash_profile to look like this:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/subl -w"
```

Then do a `git commit -v` for the message to open. Inside of the sublimeText2 window, click on the lower right corner where it says `Plain Text` and change the option to:

> Open all with current extension as > Diff

and you should get colors everytime you get the COMMIT_EDITMSG.

Comment: Nice! But I'm only seeing the deletions in red :( No pluses in green! Just to confirm...I've been using "lime" for the symlink (which I highly recommend!) and in my .gitconfig I've always used `editor = lime -w`. My alias for `$ git commit -v` is `$ gcv`.

Comment: Holy crap, this also fixed the weird center line I had running down the middle of my COMMIT_EDITMSG. You rock; kudos!

Comment: Jose and @VonC, did you see both red for deletions AND green for additions? I'm only seeing red deletions. I awarded the answer, but it isn't working for me, so not to confuse others, I unchecked it for now.

Comment: @RudyOnRails I haven't tested it yet. I'll check that later.

Comment: Jose, once you accept my edit (to include the theme code), I will accept the answer! We did it guys, it is working PERFECT :)